# 2001 Honda Accord EX (f23a4 engine)

Tags: honda, accord

codes p1166 and p1167 I have replaced the 02 sensor but light is still on, there is power to the wires and resistance on the sensor.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you clear the codes after you put the O2 sensor in? Which O2 sensor did you replace? Or did you replace all of them? You say there is power at the sensor, I'm sure that would preclude the fuse, but you might want to check it anyway.

Comment: It is the upstream sensor, I have checked the fuses as well but still cant find the issue

Comment: Have you checked for power on the ECM side of the circuit? This gen Accord has a wire that goes from the primary heater relay to the ECM to show that the relay works. If the ECM doesn't see voltage on that wire it throws those codes.